# How to extract base url using golang

Tags: go, url

Given a url string, how to retrieve only the base url (i.e. protocol://host:port)

For example

> https://example.com/user/1000 => https://example.com

> https://localhost:8080/user/1000/profile => https://localhost:8080

I've tried parsing the url with `url.Parse()` but the [net/url](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url) doesn't seem to have a method that returns the base url. I could try appending the individual parts of url to get the base url but I just wanted to check if there are any better alternatives to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would parse it using [`url.Parse()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Parse), and zero the fields you don't want in the result, namely `Path`, `RawQuery` and `Fragment`. Then the result (base URL) can be acquired using [`URL.String()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL.String).

For example:

```
u, err := url.Parse("https://user@pass:localhost:8080/user/1000/profile?p=n#abc")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(u)
u.Path = ""
u.RawQuery = ""
u.Fragment = ""
fmt.Println(u)
fmt.Println(u.String())
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/QvqfkaP9doH)):

```
https://user@pass:localhost:8080/user/1000/profile?p=n#abc
https://user@pass:localhost:8080
https://user@pass:localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
u, _ := url.Parse("https://example.com/user/1000")
val := fmt.Sprintf("%s://%s", u.Scheme, u.Host)
```

The following may be more useful in the general case.

```golang
rawURL := "https://user:pass@localhost:8080/user/1000/profile?p=n#abc"
u, _ := url.Parse(rawURL)
psw, pswSet := u.User.Password()
for _, d := range []struct {
    actual   any
    expected any
}{
    {u.Scheme, "https"},
    {u.User.Username(), "user"},
    {psw, "pass"},
    {pswSet, true},
    {u.Host, "localhost:8080"},
    {u.Path, "/user/1000/profile"},
    {u.Port(), "8080"},
    {u.RawPath, ""},
    {u.RawQuery, "p=n"},
    {u.Fragment, "abc"},
    {u.RawFragment, ""},
    {u.RequestURI(), "/user/1000/profile?p=n"},
    {u.String(), rawURL},
    {fmt.Sprintf("%s://%s", u.Scheme, u.Host), "https://localhost:8080"},
} {
    if d.actual != d.expected {
        t.Fatalf("%s\n%s\n", d.actual, d.expected)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gpVa8VVpxZw)</kbd>